# Can't turn off unconnected-port warnings in simulink using Matlab R2010b 7.11.2

Tags: matlab, warnings, simulink, user-preferences

My model has a lot of unconnected Input and Output ports, which I don't mind. So I tried turning those annoying warnings like

> Warning: Output port 3 of 'Model_ESM_6/L-ESM-6/Wankdynamik' is not
> connected.
>
> > In ESM6_resim at 1

off. I went to simulink preferences -> Diagnostics -> connectivity and then I set "unconnected block Output/Input ports" to "None". Another Simulation showed, that this had no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce your problem. For me, the warnings do not show up. I believe these are model-specific settings - are you sure you are using the same model you turned the warnings off for?

Comment: well i turned those warnings off by clicking on 'file' -> 'preferences...' in the model that i use. So they should be turned off for exactly this model, right? i might have to mention, that i have to use a quite old matlab Version (7.11.2)

Comment: Yes, that should be the case. You should probably edit the main question to include the Matlab version you use. I'm sorry, but I don't think I can do anything more to try and help you since I don't have access to the particular version you're using.

Comment: @mikkola okay, thank you anyway. I added the Version in the title. It's R2010b 7.11.2